# How does CPython match variables to values?

Tags: heap-memory, cpython, stack-memory

From what I read on other forum posts, the way CPython handles variables is, and please correct me if I'm wrong, the virtual machine creates a heap where values are stored, and the variables names, the identifiers are stored somewhere in the stack for that thread. So if `num = 5` is in my code, the value 5 would be somewhere in the heap, and the string num would appear somewhere in the stack.

What I can't find is how does CPython know how to match some variable name from the stack for its matching value. I understand it doesn't user pointers, so how DOES it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, every variable is stored in a dictionary.

```
>>> def foo():
...   bar = 123
...   baz = 'Mike!'
...   print locals()
...
>>> foo()
{'bar': 123, 'baz': 'Mike!'}
```

The `locals()` method returns all the variables that are created in the local scope.

When you label 5 with 'num', there is a dictionary which stores the string `'num'` and it's associated value of 5. Python objects are all stored in the heap, i.e. the dictionary, the string 'num', the number 5. They are all in the heap.

```
>>> num = 5
>>> print globals()
{'__builtins__': ..., 'num': 5, ...}
```

When you call a function in Python, e.g.

```
foo(123, 456, name='Mike', is_valid=True)
```

Python treats it like

```
foo(*(123, 456), **{'name': 'Mike', 'is_valid': True})
```

which maps to the [following C code](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call)

```
PyObject_CallObject(PyObject* function, PyObject* arguments, PyObject* keywords)
```

i.e. `foo` the function is actually a Python object, and so are arguments and keywords. `arguments` is a Tuple, while `keywords` is a dictionary. T[hey are all Python objects](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/23/python-internals-how-callables-work)!

So what is left on the stack frame, just a standard C function's stack frame, which contains the return address, and pointers to 3 python objects.

If you dig into the sources, you will find that Python is a beautiful piece of work.

### Reading dictionary values

Python dictionaries are Python objects which implement the [Mapping protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/mapping.html). The way dictionaries are stored are internal to the implementation. I've linked to the official API to read values from dictionaries. But here's a taste of it

```
 PyObject* PyMapping_GetItemString(PyObject *o, char *key)
```

which is equivalent to `o[key]` in Python. The Python dictionary implements the function prototype above in

```
 PyObject* PyDict_GetItemString(PyObject *p, const char *key)¶
```

The implementation of PyDict_GetItem is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1042) but I'm not familiar with it. I had a quick read of the comments on the file, and the answer to your question appears to be both. A dictionary may store it's values and keys in a single block, or swap to storing them separately. My guess is one optimises for the case of array-like indexers, while the other is more like associative arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful answer! I have a long way to go before I can actually dig in in understand everything to the core (but I definitely plan to someday). One more followup question. How are dictionaries stored in the heap? is it block for key block for value? Thanks!